# C# in VS Code missing advanced editing features

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I know this is a stupid questions but I was using VS Code to edit the scripts for my Unity project but then all of a sudden all the advanced editing features are gone. Maybe I did something wrong? I don't know how to fix this - please help.

Currently there are no reference text on top of those variables and when I right click them for more option only this show up. It seem like the problem only happen to C# files, when I try it with some Python project it work fine

[image]

Comment: Open OUTPUT panel and see what "OmniSharp Log" wrote.

Comment: It said Error: Found dotnet version 5.0.400. Minimum required version is 6.0.100.

Comment: Then you should try to install .NET 6 SDK (6.0.xxx) on this machine first.

Comment: I have 1 more minor question should I uninstall older .NET SDK version ?

Comment: Do you still need it for some reason?

Comment: I don't think so, the version 5.0 version currently on my machine is installed by Visual Studio and I don't use it as frequent anymore.

Comment: .NET 5 reached end of life on May 10, 2022, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet so it is not likely that you will need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to update my .NET SDK version to the required one to fix it